# Incremental ListView with ScrollBar

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp

I want to implement a ListView that loads new content when is scrolled (it will have over 2000 elements) with a scrollbar. This is what I have:

```
<ListView
   Width="500"
   MaxHeight="400"
   IsItemClickEnabled = "False"
   SelectionMode ="None"
   IncrementalLoadingThreshold="5"
   IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge"
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"/>
```

The list works perfectly fine but the scrollbar is not visible. How can I make it work?

Comment: that looks correct to me. since your using absolute values for your Listviews Dimensions; is it possible that the scrollbar is being covered up by some other element?

Comment: Are you using an item source that implements `ISupportIncrementalLoading`? 

As mentioned, the setup all looks fine here.

Comment: @JamesCroft I am using `Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^` as an Item source. Do I have to implement my own collection that inherits `ISupportIncrementalLoading`?

Comment: @ShawnRamirez the problem was with the fixes width. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a fixed with. After removing it, the scrollbar is visible.

Answer (score 1):

there is another way to go.
you can use "ScrollViewer" and "Stackpanel" as main content of "ScrollViewer".
then set the "Orientation". finally add list itmes as childrens of "Stackpanel"
please take a look at sample:

```
<ScrollViewer
        Width="500"
        MaxHeight="400"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
        >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" SizeChanged="items_modified_event">
            <ListViewItem Content="item1" />
            <ListViewItem Content="item2" />
            <ListViewItem Content="item3" />
            <ListViewItem Content="item4" />
            .
            .
            .
            .
        </StackPanel>           
    </ScrollViewer>
```